# Fill in "getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();" in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, quartz-scheduler, jobs

Hello i want to ask if it's possible that i fill in the Currently jobs from a Quartz Scheduler into a JTable so i can see them ?

I tried something like this..:

```
private JTable getJTableTasks() {       
String [] columnNames ={"Task", "Status"};
                Object [][] data = {
    {sched.getSched().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()},
        };
jTableTasks = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any solutions ?

Error Message with the line ({sched.getSched().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()},)

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem:      Unhandled exception type SchedulerException     at
>   taskscheduler.gui.TaskScheduler.getJTableTasks(TaskScheduler.java:294)
>     at
>   taskscheduler.gui.TaskScheduler.getJContentPane(TaskScheduler.java:88)
>     at taskscheduler.gui.TaskScheduler.getJFrame(TaskScheduler.java:68)
>     at taskscheduler.gui.TaskScheduler.access$1(TaskScheduler.java:62)
>     at taskscheduler.gui.TaskScheduler$5.run(TaskScheduler.java:349)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: *"But it doesn't work."*  Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: i edit my post.. hope this is helpful

Comment: *"Unresolved compilation problem"*  What is the *compilation error*?

Comment: I cant be use try catch in this array..
Is it that what you mean ?

Comment: Again, I mean copy/paste it from your IDE, or type it exactly as it is reported when compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill up information in 2D array in your case. Code will look something like this -

```
           Object[][] data = new Object[9][2];
            int i=0;
            List<JobExecutionContext> sf = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
            for (JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext : sf) {

                data [i][0] = jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getSchedulerName();
                data [i][1] = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getDescription();
                i++;
            }
```